# Pandas Dataframe show value in column which appears more than ten times

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Currently I am analyzing a .csv file which includes names, birthyear and gender of dogs in a given city. I want to filter out birthyears where less than 10 dogs were born.
What would be the right method to do that?

```
    name                        birth_year                gender
0   "Bobby" Lord Sinclair           2009                    m
1   "Buddy" Fortheringhay's J.      2011                    m
2   "Zappalla II" Kora v. Tüfibach  2011                    w
3   (Karl) Kaiser Karl vom Edersee  2013                    m
4   A-Diana                         2006                    w
```

The data looks somewhat like that, the list is a lot longer. What I want to do is to filter out birth_year values which occur less than 11 times.
I started with using

```
df[df["birth_year"] < 11]
```

but this obviously filters out the birth year 11 and lower itself and not the amount

Greetings

Comment: Could you please share what you have tried so far and what didn't work for you?

Comment: Please add input data, expected output and what you tried

Comment: Sure, edited it

Answer (score 0):

If you send the data.. or you can use a function like

```
df['some'] = df[df[dog] < 10];
```

or pd querys

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html

Comment: Have you tried this? You assign a dataframe to a column of a dataframe. Pretty sure it's going to produce an error. And what's up with a semicolumn?

Comment: in this example, i create a new colum in the df, try that with any example :),
and the semicolon it just because i was working on java in the exactly moment =_=

Comment: I have tried it. Throws `ValueError: Wrong number of items passed`. You can edit your post to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear whether you want to *keep* the rows in groups with 10 or less, or *throw away* the rows in groups with 10 or less. Change the `>` to `<=` appropriately.

```
g = df.groupby("birth_year")
g.filter(lambda x: x.name.count() > 10)
```